# point to 2D array using double pointer

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, implicit-conversion

**Here is code :**

```
void nextGeneration(int **board) {

int editBoard[row][col];
    ...
    displayBoard(editBoard);
}

void displayBoard(int **board) {
    ...
}
```

**I get this error msg:**

> GOL.c: In function ‘nextGeneration’: GOL.c:64: warning: passing
>   argument 1 of ‘displayBoard’ from incompatible pointer type GOL.c:28:
>   note: expected ‘int **’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)[(long
>   unsigned int)(col)]’

I just don't know how to point 2D array that will be accepted to void displayBoard(int **board) function.

How can I do that?

Thank you very much

Comment: double pointer is not a 2D array....

Comment: You could use a pointer-to-array instead, if the dimensions are fixed or can be passed to the function.  If you *really* want to pass a double pointer, you'll have to make an array of `int *`, point each pointer in it to the corresponding row of the 2D array, and pass that... but that's probably not the best way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A double pointer is not a 2D array, but you can do it using a single pointer

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define COL_WIDTH 2

int displayBoard(int *board, int row, int col)
{
    // editBoard[row][col]
    return board[(COL_WIDTH*row)+col];
}

int main(void)
{
    int board[2][COL_WIDTH] = { {1,2}, {3,4} };

    printf("%d\n", displayBoard((int *)(board), 1, 1));
    printf("%d\n", displayBoard((int *)(board), 0, 1));
}
```

Comment: C supports 2D arrays (arrays of arrays). So why not use one instead of error-prone indexing by hand? That's not even a VLA, so it will work with pre-modern C, too.

Comment: @Olaf you right but I Was answering to OP from the  pointer point of view.  The other answer shows the other way.

Answer (score 3):

An array passed to a function is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element.

So if such an array like

```
int editBoard[row][col];
```

is passed to a function as an argument it is converted to type `int ( * )[col]`. The types `int( * )[col]` and `int **` are two incompatible different types.

If the compiler supports variable length arrays then you can declare your function like

```
void nextGeneration( size_t row, size_t col, int board[row][col] );
```

or

```
void nextGeneration( size_t row, size_t col, int board[][col] );
```

or

```
void nextGeneration( size_t row, size_t col, int ( *board )[col] );
```

These three declarations declare the same one function.

If the compiler does not support VLAs but the value `col` is defined as a constant (using #define or an enumerator) then you again can use these declarations.

Another approach is to interpret the array used as an argument as a one dimensional array. In this case you can declare the function like

```
void nextGeneration( int *board, size_t row, size_t col );
```

and pass the array like

```
nextGeneration( ( int * )editBoard, row, col );
```

Answer (score -1):

Like this

```
void nextGeneration(int **board) {

int editBoard[row][col];
    ...
    displayBoard(editBoard);
}

void displayBoard(int board[][col]) {
      ...
}
```

Comment: Its working on my system.  Its also one of the listed solution from Vlad from Moscows answer

Comment: Sorry, I've misread it.